# How do I get rid of "duplicate" events with Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I recently started working on a simple project to learn about Apache Kafka. My use case is as described:

The producer fires an EVENT on the same topic and partition. The payload of the events is a simple ID number. The event represents a change on the state of some system that the consumer is monitoring.

The consumer reads the message and it takes a long time to process the event (longer than the time taken by the producer to generate multiple events). It needs to fetch current the state of the system and do something about it.

Depending on the ID number contained in the message, the consumer's processing routine is always the same.

I would like that, if multiple events were fired while processing an event  with the same ID, the consumer would process just one of those once it's ready to process more.

If the processor was processing the event A with payload ID:1 and multiple events with payload ID:1 (B C D E) were fired during this time, I would like the processor to process just one of these events, say the event E, once it is done processing the event A.

I'll add a picture to explain this better.

[link to the picture because I don't have enough reputation to put inline images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtoxE.png)

In the example above at the instant t4 the partition has two events in queue, the ones generated at instants t2 and t3.
The consumer finished processing and is available to process more events.

I would like the consumer to skip the processing of either t2 or t3, since the routine would be the same and the outcome wouldn't change.
I simplified it for the sake of explaning it, but in my case there could be thousands of events between t1 and t4, and I would want to skip all of them but one.

I would like either Kafka or the consumer to do some sort of "collapsing" of the events.

How can I achieve this behavior? Does Kafka offer some funcionality that solves my problem? Am I using the wrong tools for the job?

Comment: Assuming that your duplicate events have some kind of correlating key (e.g. transactionid) which is the same for the duplicates, have a look at the [transaction api and `enable.idempotence`](https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-exactly-once#1-a-transaction-aware-producer)

Comment: @StuartLC The producer needs to publish all the events, because they represent some state change in the system. Each event means the state of the system is changed, the consumer has to fetch that state and do its thing. I wouldn't want to miss some state change. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

P_Id denotes payload id.

1. Producer publishes: m1(P_Id:1)
2. Consumer reads m1 and starts processing
3. Producer publishes: m2(P_Id:2), m3(P_Id:1), m4(P_Id:1), m5(P_Id:2)
4. Consumer finishes processing m1.
5. Consumer reads <m2, m3, m4, m5>

Expectation: consumer need to run routines for P_Id1 and P_Id2 :

> Depending on the ID number contained in the message, the consumer's processing routine is always the same.

Kafka does not provide this feature out of the box. So this is **NOT** the ideal solution. I am only proposing it since you mentioned that you started working on it as part of learning kafka:

Iterate over the batch of messages that are read from kafka and find list of unique payload ids and run routines for them. Once processing in complete, commit your batch and read the next batch.

#### Alternative approach without Kafka

We need a data structure like <Payload_Id, Timestamp> where timestamp is the timestamp of the last event produced. This middle layer could be redis, a database table, zookeeper nodes or anything else depending on your requirements of performance and redundancy. Let me take it as database table for the sake of this explanation.

Producer upserts into the database whenever a new event occurs. Thus the table will contain the timestamp for the latest event corresponding to the payload id.
E.g. Producer state

```
Payload_Id, Timestamp
1, T1
2, T2
3, T3
```

The consumer has its own state, same structure but a different table, representing the event processed.

E.g. Consumer State

```
Payload_Id, Timestamp
1, T1+5m
2, T2
```

Consumer will now work as follows:

1. Build consumer state from db
2. Build producer state from db
3. Determine updated payload ids (1 and 3 in our example)
4. Run corresponding logic
5. Upon successful execution. update consumer state in db (in case consumer dies, it will know from where to start)
6. Go to Step2 to get new events (as consumer already has its current state)

Comment: You described the expectation correctly. When you say 'this is NOT the ideal solution' are you talking about the choice of Kafka as a message broker or the solution you suggested? 
As of now I'm using the @KafkaListener annotation in Java in the processor, I haven't explored the batchListener configuration yet but I'll definitely give it a try!
What would be your ideal appproach to solving a problem like this?

Comment: This is NOT ideal because kafka does not cater to the use case you mentioned. Depending on the load you could have thousands of messages for a payload id generating unnecessary load for the system.I have edited the answer to give an alternate approach

Comment: I like the timestamp approach, I initially thought about it but with a sequence number instead (getting rid of working with dates which I always found annoying). I didn't want to resort to a third party system (I'm already using Redis to synchronize some other things) just yet, even though it might be the only option. Thanks for the inputs!

Comment: Kafka was also a third party system by that definition I guess. Basically it is all about inter process communication, having some sort of middle layer like kafka/redis/db just decouples the producer and consumer.